# Outlook 2013 rule to redirect mail not working

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, redirection

I set up a rule to forward all incoming mail and it did not work.

Tried the same with a redirect in the rule instead of forward.

I've essentially done step by step everything in [this guide](https://www.library.illinois.edu/it/helpdesk/exchange/redirect.html), and still no dice.

I logged in to the webmail service and made a rule there and still, it does not work.

The email is an outside domain, my other rules that sort emails to folders are working fine.

I read [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other-mso_o365b/rule-to-forward-email-is-not-working/9093b4dd-42b7-41db-af05-778f511e2b95) on Microsoft.com and it said

> UPDATE:
>   In Outlook.com/Settings/Options/Mail/Accounts there is a heading called Forwarding.
>   When I clicked this, a message appeared to say that Forwarding was turned off (even tho' my rule was ON), to discourage Spam.

However that setting is nowhere to be found on our webmail service or in outlook.

What additional steps might be needed to get the redirect or forwarding rules working? I have access to the exchange server if necessary. I only want to set this rule up on one account.

Comment: It could be that your company do not allow that due to security and data leak protection. Did you checked that with your IT if you are allowed to perform that?

Comment: @BastianW yes I am allowed. However there might be a setting preventing it somewhere. Optimally we would turn that setting off for a single outlook mailbox not company wide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok based on your comment the following apply then here:

*Your Exchange administrator is able to control that feature company wide and you need to get in contact with him in order to solve that.*

That means he can control that globally for the whole Exchange infrastructure inside the Organization Configuration. As we do not know how your Exchange server is configured you need to work with your MS Exchange administrator to check / change that. As we on SuperUser couldn´t answer administrator specified questions (ServerFault would be the correct community for Administrators) your Administrator should re-view the following Microsoft documentation to help you and/or adjust the environment if needed (You alone couldn´t adjust that):

- [How to Override Blocked Auto-Forwarding for Select Users](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317652/how-to-override-blocked-auto-forwarding-for-select-users)
- [How to prevent internal users from autoforwaring mails to external recipients](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/lystavlen/2012/04/10/how-to-prevent-internal-users-from-autoforwaring-mails-to-external-recipients/)
- [Control allowing automatic replies / forwards via Hub Transport](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997208(EXCHG.80).aspx)